# How can I get the name of the namespace from a SOAP message?

Tags: xml, soap, namespaces

I have a SOAP message (see below).

Using Xpath, how can I extract the name of the namespace from this message?  In other words, is there an Xpath routine that will return the text "validateNewOrder"?

Any suggestions or help would be invaluable.  I have been searching everywhere but not found an solution.  It is driving me crazy...

Thanks!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:validateNewOrder xmlns:ns1="http://sire.rabobank.nl/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <sireheader xmlns="http://sire.rabobank.nl/">
       <sender>
         <compid>TEST</compid>
       </sender>
     </sireheader>
     <order xmlns="http://sire.rabobank.nl/">
       <account>123456789</account>
     </order>
   </ns1:validateNewOrder>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: `validateNewOrder` in your example has nothing to do with namespaces, it's the element's local name. The namespace URI is `http://sire.rabobank.nl/`, and the namespace prefix is `ns1`. There's no such thing as a "namespace name".

Comment: Thanks - that starts to make things clearer!  

Do you have any suggestions then about how I can retrieve the elemen'ts local name?  I am pulling what's left of my hair out trying to get the write syntax for my Xpath query.

Olly

Comment: Hi Skaddman.  I have my solution now.  Thanks for your help.  olly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local-name(/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[1])
```

Returns the local name of the first element underneath `Body` in a namespace agnostic way.

Tested it with (c#)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
var xpath = "local-name(/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[1])";
var res = doc.Root.XPathEvaluate(xpath);
```

Comment: Hi Obalix

Thanks.  I tried your suggestion, but it gave a syntax error.  So I tried
    //*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[local-name(*[1])]

But that gave me "TEST123456789", not "validateNewOrder".  Do you know what I am doing wrong?  I am new to SOAP, so am still misunderstanding lots of stuff.

Ps - I was using the site http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx to test my Xpath query

Thanks!

Olly

Comment: @olly: Ok, there were two errors in the query, fixed them and tested the query with the supplied code. The site you quoted can only process queries that return a node set. So if you want to test whether the right element is selected, just drop the outer `local-name()` and paste the rest into the tool. I.e. `/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[1]`

Comment: Hi Obalix.  Thanks for the fix.  However, when I paste it into the tool, the tool returns "TEST12345689".  This is not what I want to retrieve.  What I want to be returned is the value "validateNewOrder".  Or have I misunderstood your answer.  Sorry if my question seems dumb, but I am new to SOAP...

Comment: Hi Obelix.  You are a genius, and I was being dumb.  I tried your query in my Java code and it gives me exactly what I want!  Thanks!!!

Comment: @olly: then just accept the question, if you want you can up-vote as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have my solution, thanks to user Obelix.

The Xpath query that I needed was

```
local-name(/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/*[local-name() = 'Body']/*[1])
```

It does not work on the test site that I was using (apparently, the site I quoted can only process queries that return a node set), but does work in my Java code.

Now I can go out and enjoy the weekend

Olly

Comment: @olly: It is not good style to requote a solution someone else provided you with. However, it <b>is</b> good style to accept and/or upvote the person who provided you with the solution and thus reward them for their effort.

Comment: Sorry Obalix - I have not used this before.  I think I have credited your answer to you now.  Let me know if it didn't work.  I do not have an account yet to try and promote your answer, but when I get that sorted, I will promote your answer.